# How to execute Selenium ExpectedConditions based on string variables

Tags: vb.net, selenium

VERY LONG story short, I'm trying to develop a MS Excel AddIn to allow an uneducated user (open to interpretation) to create Excel-based scripts that Visual Basic (yeah not C#) can essentially parse into the individual pieces and send to the browser via Selenium commands.  So far, I've had quite a bit of success.  Granted there is a little bit clunkiness, but this is round 1, and I've only been working with Selenium for a week.

Up to this point I have been able to use the CallByName function to call various Selenium methods where each _argument is passed from a higher level handler originating from values in spreadsheet cells.

```
Dim eleActionElement as Remote.RemoteWebElement = Nothing
eleActionElement = driver.FindeElement(By.Id("PresentObjectID"))
CallByName(eleActionElement, _strAction, CallType.Method, _strActionArg)
```

Initially I had problems with Bys:

```
Dim myBy As By = CallByName(By, _strBy, CallType.Method, _strByArg)
```

Intelisense warns that "By" is a class type and cannot be used as an expression.  Fortunately, there are individual methods for each by type, so I have been able to retrieve elements effectively through:

```
Public Function DriverFindElementBy(_strBy As String, _strByArg As String) As Remote.RemoteWebElement

    Dim strElementBy As String = "FindElementBy" & _strBy
    Dim eleWebElement As Remote.RemoteWebElement = Nothing

    eleWebElement = CallByName(ThisAddIn.driver, strElementBy, CallType.Method, _strByArg)
    Return eleWebElement
End Function
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to get ExpectedConditions to work.  My best guess (of many) is:

```
Public Function WaitOnCondition(_strCondition As String, _strBy As String, _strByArg As String)

    Dim myExpectedConditionObj As ExpectedConditions

    CallByName(myExpectedConditionObj, _strCondition, CallType.Method)
    waitDefault.Until(CallByName(myExpectedConditionObj, _strCondition, CallType.Method))
    If strTestResult.Length = 0 Then
        Return "Success"
    Else
        Return strTestResult.ToString
    End If
End Function
```

Intelisense warns this could result in a NullReference and it does.  I can see how the object is not instantiated yet, but the same approach worked with the RemoteWebElement.  If studied the Selenium docs, and both are class types; so I'm left thinking the problem has to do with various methods of the ExpectedConditions and By classes take and return different numbers and types of arguments.  It may be because both classes are delegates.  It may be some simple error I'm making - although, I've written and rewritten these functions a dozen times with the recurring thought, "geez, this should work."  One of those times you'd think I'd have blindly gotten it right.

I'm certainly not a .Net expert and advanced techniques can be baffling at times, but I do study the solutions people provide on SO and often have to go and expand my skills; so please know that nay help will be appreciate and will not go in vain.

One tiny request, if you give a C# (or Java or Python) explanation, just let me know if you KNOW / DON'T KNOW or AREN'T SURE if it will work in VB. My biggest challenge in advanced topics is that narrow segment of stuff that doesn't crossover between C# and VB.
THANKS in advance!

Comment: Where is the code actually breaking? It does not look like you are instantiating 'myExpectedConditionObj' as a new instance of the class?

Comment: Intelisense says there is no New accessible for ExpectedConditions.